Calculate Duration
I am attempting use the script activity to log data about an automation and its duration. I have two scripts one to run at the beginning of the automation and one at the end. This initial one is working fine, the second one I am is where I'm having issues. I've tried using the Date data type inital which hadn't worked and now I am attempting to use the Text data type and parse the out each section of the time. Any insight would be extremely valued
Start script:
    <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    try {
        /* Getting current date and time */
        var now = Platform.Function.Now();
        
        /* Set the field values, intially these will be hard code with plans to house information about each automation in a seperate DE */
        var automationName = "AUTOMATION_NAME_TEST";
        var autoCode = "AUTO_CODE_TEST";
        var triggerMethod = "TRIGGER_METHOD_TEST";
        var client = "CLIENTTEST"; /* Isn't in screaming snake beacuse this field has a mx lenght of 10 sorry not sorry*/
        var sender = false; /* Boolean value */
        var version = "VERSION_TEST";
        var startDate = now;
        var endDate = null;
        var duration = null;


        /* Initializes the DE object */
        var de = DataExtension.Init("ALog");

        /* Organizes the variables into JSON to be insert into the DE*/
        var data = {
            AUTOMATION_NAME:automationName,
            AUTO_CODE:autoCode,
            TRIGGER_METHOD:triggerMethod,
            CLIENT:client,
            SENDER:sender,
            VERSION:version,
            START_DATE:startDate,
            END_DATE:endDate,
            DURATION:duration

        };
        de.Rows.Add(data);
    } catch (e) {
    /* Planning for failed inserts to provide an error message to the error log */
    }
</script>

End script:
    <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    
    function parseDateTime(dateTimeString) {
    var dateAndTime = dateTimeString.split(" ");
    var datePart = dateAndTime[0];
    var timePart = dateAndTime[1];
    var amPmPart = dateAndTime[2];
    var dateComponents = datePart.split("/");
    var timeComponents = timePart.split(":");
    var month = parseInt(dateComponents[0], 10);
    var day = parseInt(dateComponents[1], 10);
    var year = parseInt(dateComponents[2], 10);
    var hour = parseInt(timeComponents[0], 10);
    var minute = parseInt(timeComponents[1], 10);
    var second = parseInt(timeComponents[2], 10);
    if (amPmPart === "PM" && hour !== 12) {
        hour += 12;
    } else if (amPmPart === "AM" && hour === 12) {
        hour = 0;
    }
    return [month, day, year, hour, minute, second];
}

// Function to calculate time difference and format as text
function calculateTimeDifference(startDateString, endDateString) {
    var startComponents = parseDateTime(startDateString);
    var endComponents = parseDateTime(endDateString);
    var startYear = startComponents[2];
    var startMonth = startComponents[0];
    var startDay = startComponents[1];
    var startHour = startComponents[3];
    var startMinute = startComponents[4];
    var startSecond = startComponents[5];
    var endYear = endComponents[2];
    var endMonth = endComponents[0];
    var endDay = endComponents[1];
    var endHour = endComponents[3];
    var endMinute = endComponents[4];
    var endSecond = endComponents[5];

    var diffYears = endYear - startYear;
    var diffMonths = endMonth - startMonth;
    var diffDays = endDay - startDay;
    var diffHours = endHour - startHour;
    var diffMinutes = endMinute - startMinute;
    var diffSeconds = endSecond - startSecond;

    if (diffSeconds < 0) {
        diffSeconds += 60;
        diffMinutes -= 1;
    }
    if (diffMinutes < 0) {
        diffMinutes += 60;
        diffHours -= 1;
    }
    if (diffHours < 0) {
        diffHours += 24;
        diffDays -= 1;
    }
    if (diffDays < 0) {
        var daysInPrevMonth = new Date(endYear, endMonth - 1, 0).getDate();
        diffDays += daysInPrevMonth;
        diffMonths -= 1;
    }
    if (diffMonths < 0) {
        diffMonths += 12;
        diffYears -= 1;
    }

    var formattedDifference = "";
    if (diffYears === 0 && diffMonths === 0 && diffDays === 0) {
        formattedDifference = 
            (diffHours < 10 ? "0" + diffHours : diffHours) + ":" + 
            (diffMinutes < 10 ? "0" + diffMinutes : diffMinutes) + ":" + 
            (diffSeconds < 10 ? "0" + diffSeconds : diffSeconds);
    } else {
        formattedDifference = 
            (diffDays < 10 ? "0" + diffDays : diffDays) + ":" + 
            (diffHours < 10 ? "0" + diffHours : diffHours) + ":" + 
            (diffMinutes < 10 ? "0" + diffMinutes : diffMinutes) + ":" + 
            (diffSeconds < 10 ? "0" + diffSeconds : diffSeconds);
    }

    return formattedDifference;
}

    try {
        // Initialize the Data Extension
        var automationLog = DataExtension.Init("ALog"); // Replace "ALog" with your Data Extension's external key

        // Define the AUTO_CODE value to look for
        var autoCodeValue = "AUTO_CODE_TEST"; // Replace with your specific AUTO_CODE value

        // Filter to retrieve the record with the specified AUTO_CODE
        var autoCodeFilter = {
            Property: "AUTO_CODE",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: autoCodeValue
        };

        // Retrieve the record
        var results = automationLog.Rows.Retrieve(autoCodeFilter);

        if (results.length > 0) {
            // Get the first record from the results
            var row = results[0];

            // Check if START_DATE is present
            if (row.START_DATE) {
                // Parse START_DATE and calculate duration
                var startDateStr = row.START_DATE;
                var endDateStr = Now().ToString();
                var duration = calculateTimeDifference(startDateStr, endDateStr);

                // Update the record's END_DATE and DURATION fields
                var timeUpdate = {
                    END_DATE:endDateStr,
                    DURATION:duration
                };  

                // Update the record in the Data Extension
                var updateResult = automationLog.Rows.Update(timeUpdate, ["AUTO_CODE"], [autoCodeValue]);

            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle any errors that might occur
        // Optional: Implement error logging here
    }
</script>


Have you considered using _AutomationInstance and _AutomationActivityInstance Data Views to pull the data about the automation run duration?

Would it not be easier to use data views?
https://sfmarketing.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/dataviews_2022_v3.jpg
You can use the [_AutomationInstance] (bottom center of the link above) data view to pull through the automation data.
Then use columns "AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC" & "AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC" for start and end.
Then simply add a field in your DE with the differnce..... you can use the below calculation for the duration

SELECT 

    MemberID
,   AutomationName
,   AutomationDescription
,   AutomationCustomerKey
,   AutomationType
,   AutomationNotificationRecipient_Complete
,   AutomationNotificationRecipient_Error
,   AutomationNotificationRecipient_Skip
,   AutomationStepCount
,   AutomationInstanceID
,   AutomationInstanceIsRunOnce
,   FilenameFromTrigger
,   AutomationInstanceScheduledTime_UTC
,   AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC
,   AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC
,   AutomationInstanceStatus
,   AutomationInstanceActivityErrorDetails
,     RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, AutomationInstanceStartTime_UTC, AutomationInstanceEndTime_UTC) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) AS Duration_HHMMSS_TXT

FROM _AUTOMATIONINSTANCE



